# How to solve this celery Error: Unable to load celery application. Module 'forecast' has no attribute 'celery'

Tags: python, django, django-models, celery, django-celery

I am trying to seting up Celery and Amazon SQS  for my project but faced with problems. I did following. I put celery.py file inside my project directory where settings py located. Here is snapshot of my project

```
--predictions
     --forecast
        --dataflow
        --forecast
              **  __init__.py
              **  celery.py
              **  urls.py
               ** settings.py
               ** wsgi.py
        --manage.py
     --env
```

I doted with "--" folders and with "**" files. Inside celery.py file i have the folliwing code

```
from __future__ import      
absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery                       


os.environ.setdefault
('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE',
'forecast.settings')

app = Celery('forecast')
app.config_from_object
('django.conf:settings')

app.autodiscover_tasks()

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
'display_time-30-seconds':   
{ 'task':  'demoapp.tasks.display_time',
    'schedule': 10.0
 },
}                                                 
@app.task(bind=True)                             
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request:     
    {0r}'.format(self.request))
```

Inside settings.py file i set up Amazon credentials,broker_url etc

```
#settings.py
# AWS Credentials                                 
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = ('lol')      
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY =    
('Lol')                                                                              

# Celery                                          
BROKER_URL = "sqs://%s:%s@" %   
(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, 
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)                        
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = 
['application/json']    
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'               
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'                 
CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'test.fifo'              
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = None # 
Disabling the results backend

BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS =    
{'region': 'us-west-2',                          
'polling_interval': 20,}
```

Inside **init**.py file i put the following code

```
from __future__ import   
absolute_import, unicode_literals
from .celery import app as 
celery_app__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

Then i added in my django app task.py which contain the following code

```
from datetime import datetime                   
from celery import shared_task                  
@shared_task
def display_time(x, y):                                
     print("The time is %s :" % 
     str(datetime.now()))                                                 
     return True
```

after it i create inside AWS default queue. Than inside predictions folder in  terminal i run the following command

```
celery -A forecast worker -l info
```

Which give me Error

```
Error: Unable to load celery 
application. Module 'forecast' has no 
attribute 'celery'
```

When i run this command inside predictions/forecast folder its give traceback about many errors some of them in models.py file. Here is Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/
home/storage/predictions/env/bin/
celery", line 10, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/
home/storage/predictions/env/lib/   
python3.7/site-packages/celery/ 
__main__.py", line 16, in main
_main()
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/   
home/storage/predictions/env/lib/
python3.7/site-packages/celery/bin/
celery.py", line 322, in main
cmd.execute_from_commandline
(argv)
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/
home/storage/predictions/env/lib/
python3.7/site-packages/celery/bin/
celery.py", line 496, in 
execute_from_commandline
super(CeleryCommand, self)
.execute_from_commandline(argv)))
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/
home/storage/predictions/env/lib/
python3.7/site-packages/celery/bin/ 
base.py", line 298, in 
execute_from_commandline
return 
self.handle_argv(self.prog_name, 
argv[1:])
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/  
home/storage/predictions/env/lib/
python3.7/site-packages/celery/bin/
celery.py", line 488, in handle_argv
return self.execute(command, argv)
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/  
home/storage/predictions/env/lib/
python3.7/site-packages/celery/bin/
celery.py", line 420, in execute
).run_from_argv(self.prog_name, 
argv[1:], command=argv[0])
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/
home/storage/predictions/env/lib/
python3.7/site-packages/celery/bin/
worker.py", line 223, in run_from_argv
return self(*args, **options)
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/
home/storage/predictions/env/lib/
python3.7/site-packages/celery/bin/
base.py", line 252, in __call__
ret = self.run(*args, **kwargs)
return 
self.handle_argv(self.prog_name,   
argv[1:])
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/   
home/storage/predictions/env/lib/
python3.7/site-packages/celery/bin/
celery.py", line 488, in handle_argv
return self.execute(command, argv)
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/
home/storage/predictions/env/lib/
python3.7/site-packages/celery/bin/
celery.py", line 420, in execute
).run_from_argv(self.prog_name,    
argv[1:], command=argv[0])
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/ 
home/storage/predictions/env/lib/
python3.7/site-packages/celery/bin/
worker.py", line 223, in run_from_argv
return self(*args, **options)
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/
home/storage/predictions/env/lib/
python3.7/site-packages/celery/bin/
base.py", line 252, in __call__
ret = self.run(*args, **kwargs)
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/
home/storage/predictions/env/lib/
python3.7/site-packages/celery/bin/
worker.py", line 257, in run
**kwargs)
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/   
home/storage/predictions/env/lib/
python3.7/site-packages/celery/bin/
worker.py", line 223, in run_from_argv
return self(*args, **options)
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/
home/storage/predictions/env/lib/
python3.7/site-packages/celery/bin/
base.py", line 252, in __call__
ret = self.run(*args, **kwargs)
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/
home/storage/predictions/env/lib/
python3.7/site-packages/celery/bin/
worker.py", line 257, in run
**kwargs)
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/
home/storage/predictions/env/lib/
python3.7/site-packages/celery/
worker/worker.py", line 96, in __init__
self.app.loader.init_worker()
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/  
home/storage/predictions/env/lib/
python3.7/site-packages/celery/
loaders/base.py", line 114, in  
init_worker
self.import_default_modules()
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/  
home/storage/predictions/env/lib/
python3.7/site-packages/celery/
loaders/base.py", line 108, in 
import_default_modules
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/     
home/storage/predictions/env/lib/
python3.7/site-packages/celery/utils/
dispatch/signal.py", line 288, in send
response = receiver(signal=self,    
sender=sender, **named)
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/
home/storage/predictions/env/lib/
python3.7/site-packages/celery/
fixups/django.py", line 84, in 
on_import_modules
self.worker_fixup.validate_models()
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/
home/storage/predictions/env/lib/
python3.7/site-packages/celery/
fixups/django.py", line 122, in 
validate_models
self.django_setup()
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/
home/storage/predictions/env/lib/
python3.7/site-packages/celery/
fixups/django.py", line 118, in    
django_setup
django.setup()
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/
home/storage/predictions/env/lib/
python3.7/site-packages/django/ 
__init__.py", line 24, in setup  
apps.populate
(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/
home/storage/predictions/env/lib/
python3.7/site-packages/django/   
apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
app_config.import_models()

File "/data/data/com.termux/files/
home/storage/predictions/env/lib/
python3.7/site-packages/django/
apps/config.py", line 211, in 
import_models
self.models_module=import_module
(models_module_name)

File "/data/data/com.termux/files/
home/storage/predictions/env/lib/
python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 
127, in import_module  return 
_bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], 
package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", 
line 1006, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", 
line 983, in _find_and_load

File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", 
line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", 
line 677, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen 
importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 
724, in exec_module
File "<frozen 
importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 
860, in get_code
File "<frozen 
importlib._bootstrap_external
File "<frozen 
importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 
860, in get_code
File "<frozen 
importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 
791, in source_to_code
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", 
line 219, in 
_call_with_frames_removed
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/ 
home/storage/predictions/forecast/
dataflow/models.py", line 78
 home_startXI = models.JSONField()               
 home_substitutes = 
 models.JSONField()           
 away_formation = 
 models.CharField(null=True)    
 away_startXI = models.JSONField()               
 away_substitutes = 
 models.JSONField()
                                                               ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What i should do to solve this problem

Answer (score 4):

This may not solve the entire issue but

```py
from .celery import app as 
celery_app__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

Should read

```py
from .celery import app as celery_app
__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. You just need to check that you're in the right directory.

Run `cd forecast` if you're in the `predictions` directory.

That should workout fine because celery tries to look for celery app settings in `predictions/forecast/` which doesn't exist. Your celery app is in `predictions/forecast/forecast/`, that is, inside your django project directory.

Comment: That was my issue. I was running `python project/migrate.py celery` when I should be running `cd project` then `python migrate.py celery`.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help newbie like me:

You should give the full project name to workers: 
`celery worker --app config.celery.app`

Here are my observation in django.Project folder structure is

```
abc/
   config/
     celery.py
           - os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings")
           - app = Celery("test")
     settings.py
```

if you follow the same folder structure as specified in doc and task app naming convention then you can give application name(let say test) to workers
`celery worker --app test`

```
abc/
  test/
     celery.py
           - os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "test.settings")
           - app = Celery("test")
     settings.py
```

then celery auto-detect test.celery.applcation

Answer (score 0):

In **init**.py of your forecast directory add following and try to restart this might work:

```
    from .celery import app as celery_app
    __all__ = ('celery_app',)
```